# AS3 Timer problems

Tags: actionscript-3, class, addeventlistener

So I've just started attempting to merge from AS2 to AS3, and already things aren't acting like they logically should be. I'm trying to make a simple time-based particle system that makes a firework-looking effect with just a glowing ball movie clip. There's a Main class and a class for the glowing ball called Ball. The problem is when I change the addEventListener in the Main class that spawns the circles to: stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK...) the circles don't all start at the same point (at the center) for some reason, and the longer I wait to click the further away from each other they spawn... What in the world am I doing wrong??

**Main Class:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, downed);
        }

        private function downed(event:Event){
                for(var i:int = 0; i < 50; i++){
                    var a:Ball = new Ball(275, 200, randomSpeed(), randomSpeed());
                    addChild(a);
                }
        }

        private function randomSpeed():int{
            var speed:int = Math.random()*150;
            if(Math.random() > .5){
                speed *= -1;
            }
            return speed;
        }
    }
}
```

**Ball Class:**

```
package  {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Ball extends MovieClip {
        private var speedX, speedY:Number;
        private var lastTime:int;
        private var gravity:int = 3.5;

        public function Ball(x:int, y:int, dx:int, dy:int):void {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            speedX = dx;
            speedY = dy;
            lastTime -= getTimer();
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
        }

        private function moveBall(event:Event){
            var timePassed:int = getTimer()-lastTime;
            lastTime += timePassed;

            this.x += (speedX*timePassed)/1000;
            this.y += (speedY*timePassed)/1000;
            speedY += gravity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out the event listener for the `ENTER_FRAME` event in `Ball`. That way you can see whether `moveBall()` has anything to do with the issue (since it looks like the only piece of code that translates the ball). You might want to put some `trace` statements around the place as well. These can help debug these sort of problems, as they will let you know when which parts are executed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I commented out the enterframe in Ball and made it trace all the inputs instead, and changed the "new Ball(...)" function to place the explosion at mouseX and mouseY. Sure enough, all the passed variables are fine, the circles are placed at mouseX and Y... it's the moveBall function that's making them fly out of wack, but I still don't see the problem lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your moveBall() method you are using **getTimer()**

Adobe says:
For a Flash runtime processing ActionScript 3.0, this method returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the Flash runtime virtual machine for ActionScript 3.0 (AVM2) started.

This means that the value returned from getTimer() will continue to grow as you wait to click.

That is why you are experiencing the balls initializing further apart - the speed value of each ball is increased the longer you wait to click, thus moving each ball instantly to the first location the speed value corresponds to, which will be an ever further distance the longer you wait.  This doesn't occur when you use the added to stage event because the balls are instantly added the moment the flash file starts to run, and the value from getTimer() is 0 or too small to notice.

What is your intention?  to speed up the balls as they move or slow them down?  If the latter you would subtract a friction value from the ball velocity each time the loop runs.

```
public function moveBall(event:Event)
{
    var friction:Number = .7;
    speedX *= friction;
    speedY *= friction;

    this.x += speedX;
    this.y += speedY;
}
```

Also, just a few tips:  Its better to put all your particles into an array, so you have access to all of them for removing from stage, collision detection etc.  It is also a better idea to have an update loop in your Main class that iterates through that array of particles and calls an update method in each particle, rather than each particle having its own enterFrame event.  That way you can do things like stopping all particles, for instance, when you want to pause a game, or have the ability to clean up event listeners for memory management.

Comment: Well that's what I've been thinking it was, though I wasn't sure... I'm only using the timer to make the animation time based instead of frame rate based, I can code any other physics myself once I'm familiar with AS3. Is there a workaround for this? I'd love to be able to implement time based animations into further scripts.

Comment: My aplogies if the scope of my answer covers things you already know, but time based animation is NOT the way to go.  Consider how the timer runs:  In Flash the timer does not run according to strict time.  It runs as close to the designated tick as possible while still trying to complete all the code it needs to execute.  A complicated loop with lots of tasks to do per loop will cause the loop to slowly go off tick, since the timer will not be allowed to loop again until all code executes in the current loop.  This will explain it much better: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=910

Comment: I made a test out of your code.  Changing the moveBall() method to something like what I have suggested above fixed it.

Comment: Why not? My time based animations would always work flawlessly in AS2, and they look just as clean in both AS2 and AS3 when done right. There's definitely something I'm missing here. It's not like adding a few explosion pieces(of course not 50 in the long run) to the stage would lag your system unless you're on a 1900s nokia phone...

Comment: Why not is explained in the link I posted.

Comment: I'm not talking about user noticeable performance degradation, but rather the accuracy of using a timer in Flash.  Anyway, the question is answered:  you are experiencing what you were experiencing from using getTimer().  If you really want to use a timer, it should be instantiated at the scope where you added your event listener in the Ball class, and call the same method your enterframe does: moveBall().  Example: var myTimer:Timer = new Timer( intervalInMilliseconds );
myTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, moveBall );
myTimer.start();

Comment: Hm, I'll check more out about the timer. Thanks for the help though! 
Too bad the getTime number has gotten so huge we cant use it in ints, otherwise I'd consider using it as time reference.

Comment: I hate having to do this, but I might have not read that article well enough.  It looks like a good read for someone who wants to use timers in Flash, but I took it to mean that using the enterframe event was better.  After a quick read it appears enterframe is subject to the same issues.  Anyway, happy to help, if it was any help at all!   Thanks for the checkmark.  :)